# How to get all task results in Bazel output

Tags: bazel

I'm running Bazel (via Bazelisk) in CI and struggling to get reasonable output from builds. I'd like to see the result of *all* tests and/or targets in the output (even if they were completed by the cache) so developers can be sure the thing they've written is being tested.

The most obvious thing would be to set the `--show_task_finish` flag, but unfortunately [that flag doesn't seem to work](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/14052). I haven't found any flag that will reliably print out the results of tests or targets. I unfortunately cannot print stdout/stderr from tests that pass as they generate too much output.

For example, some slightly redacted output I encountered recently is nearly completely useless if I want to be sure a specific target was tested:

```
bazel test //...
(23:19:36) INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=0 --terminal_columns=0
(23:19:36) INFO: Reading rc options for 'test' from /home/bazelisk/project/.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'common' options: --attempt_to_print_relative_paths --show_timestamps --experimental_allow_tags_propagation
(23:19:36) INFO: Reading rc options for 'test' from /home/bazelisk/.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'common' options: --color=yes --curses=no --show_progress_rate_limit=0.25 --show_task_finish --announce_rc
(23:19:36) INFO: Reading rc options for 'test' from /home/bazelisk/project/.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'build' options: --keep_going --verbose_failures --local_cpu_resources=HOST_CPUS*0.5 --local_ram_resources=HOST_RAM*0.5
(23:19:36) INFO: Reading rc options for 'test' from /home/bazelisk/.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'build' options: --local_cpu_resources=HOST_CPUS --local_ram_resources=HOST_RAM*.67
(23:19:36) INFO: Reading rc options for 'test' from /home/bazelisk/project/.bazelrc:
  'test' options: --test_output=errors --test_summary=detailed --test_env=LANG=en_US.utf8 --test_env=LOCALE_ARCHIVE
(23:19:36) INFO: Reading rc options for 'test' from /home/bazelisk/.bazelrc:
  'test' options: --test_verbose_timeout_warnings
(23:19:36) INFO: Current date is <blah>
(23:19:36) Loading: 
(23:19:36) Loading: 0 packages loaded
(23:19:47) Analyzing: 48 targets (0 packages loaded)
(23:19:47) INFO: Build option --test_env has changed, discarding analysis cache.
(23:19:47) Analyzing: 48 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
(23:19:48) INFO: Analyzed 48 targets (0 packages loaded, 13812 targets configured).
(23:19:48) INFO: Found 25 targets and 23 test targets...
(23:19:48) [0 / 3] [Prepa] BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt
(23:19:50) [2,529 / 2,551] 2 / 23 tests; Testing // ... (22 actions running)
(23:19:53) [2,532 / 2,551] 5 / 23 tests; Testing // ... (19 actions running)
(23:19:56) [2,533 / 2,551] 5 / 23 tests; Testing // ... (18 actions running)
(23:19:59) [2,534 / 2,551] 6 / 23 tests; Testing // ... (17 actions running)
(23:20:05) [2,535 / 2,551] 8 / 23 tests; Testing // ... (16 actions running)
(23:20:11) [2,536 / 2,551] 8 / 23 tests; Testing // ... (15 actions running)
(23:20:16) [2,539 / 2,551] 11 / 23 tests; Testing // ... (12 actions running)
(23:20:22) [2,541 / 2,551] 14 / 23 tests; Testing // ... (10 actions running)
(23:20:32) [2,544 / 2,551] 17 / 23 tests; Testing // ... (7 actions running)
(23:20:44) [2,546 / 2,551] 18 / 23 tests; Testing // ... (5 actions running)
(23:20:54) [2,546 / 2,551] 18 / 23 tests; Testing // ... (5 actions running)
(23:21:06) [2,547 / 2,551] 19 / 23 tests; Testing // ... (4 actions running)
(23:21:29) [2,549 / 2,551] 21 / 23 tests; Testing // ... (2 actions running)
(23:21:59) [2,549 / 2,551] 21 / 23 tests; Testing // ... (2 actions running)
(23:22:27) [2,549 / 2,551] 21 / 23 tests; Testing // ... (2 actions running)
(23:22:50) INFO: Elapsed time: 193.959s, Critical Path: 181.09s
(23:22:50) INFO: 24 processes: 24 processwrapper-sandbox.
(23:22:50) INFO: Build completed successfully, 24 total actions
Test cases: finished with 417 passing and 0 failing out of 417 test cases

Executed 23 out of 23 tests: 23 tests pass.
(23:22:50) INFO: Build completed successfully, 24 total actions

CircleCI received exit code 0
```

For convenience, the fully expanded flags for this run look like:

```sh
bazel test \
  --announce_rc \
  --attempt_to_print_relative_paths \
  --color=yes \
  --curses=no \
  --experimental_allow_tags_propagation \
  --isatty=0 \
  --keep_going \
  --local_cpu_resources=HOST_CPUS \
  --local_ram_resources=HOST_RAM*.67 \
  --show_progress_rate_limit=0.25 \
  --show_task_finish \
  --show_timestamps \
  --terminal_columns=0 \
  --test_env=LANG=en_US.utf8 \
  --test_env=LOCALE_ARCHIVE \
  --test_output=errors \
  --test_summary=detailed \
  --test_verbose_timeout_warnings \
  --verbose_failures \
  //...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[--show_result=1000000](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/user-manual.html#flag--show_result) will show all of the targets (make the number as big as necessary to include all of your targets). That tends to be a lot of output though. Also note that for tests it indicates the test binary was built, not that it was run.

[--test_summary=short](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/user-manual.html#flag--test_summary) is the way to print information about each test.

Comment: I'll give those a shot, can't believe I missed that the `short` summary might provide more information if the test passed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like with `--test_summary=detailed`, Bazel prints information only about failed tests: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/command-line-reference.html#flag--test_summary

Using the default value of `short` for `--test_summary` gives all the targets:

```
$ for i in $(seq 50); do echo "exit 0" > test$i.sh; done
$ chmod +x *.sh
$ for i in $(seq 50); do echo "sh_test(
  name = 'test$i',
  srcs = ['test$i.sh'],
)" >> BUILD; done
```

with `detailed`:

```
$ bazel test //... --test_summary=detailed
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Analyzed 50 targets (24 packages loaded, 380 targets configured).
INFO: Found 50 test targets...
INFO: Elapsed time: 10.812s, Critical Path: 0.33s
INFO: 201 processes: 101 internal, 100 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 201 total actions
Test cases: finished with 50 passing and 0 failing out of 50 test cases

Executed 50 out of 50 tests: 50 tests pass.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 201 total actions
```

and with `short`:

```
$ bazel test //... --test_summary=short
INFO: Analyzed 50 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 50 test targets...
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.162s, Critical Path: 0.02s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
//:test1                                                        (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test10                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test11                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test12                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.0s
//:test13                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test14                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test15                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test16                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test17                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test18                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test19                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test2                                                        (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test20                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.0s
//:test21                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test22                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test23                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test24                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test25                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test26                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test27                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test28                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test29                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test3                                                        (cached) PASSED in 0.0s
//:test30                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test31                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test32                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test33                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test34                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test35                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test36                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//:test37                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.0s
//:test38                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test39                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test4                                                        (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test40                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.0s
//:test41                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test42                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test43                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test44                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.0s
//:test45                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test46                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test47                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.0s
//:test48                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test49                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test5                                                        (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test50                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test6                                                        (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test7                                                        (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test8                                                        (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test9                                                        (cached) PASSED in 0.1s

Executed 0 out of 50 tests: 50 tests pass.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

with `detailed` and a test failure:

```
$ bazel test //... --test_summary=detailed
INFO: Analyzed 50 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 50 test targets...
FAIL: //:test2 (see /home/ahumesky/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ahumesky/d7e5f46ce97861928779430e418f94f3/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/testlogs/test2/test.log)
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.124s, Critical Path: 0.04s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
//:test2                                                                 FAILED in 0.0s
    ERROR   .test2 (0.0s)
Test cases: finished with 49 passing and 1 failing out of 50 test cases

Executed 1 out of 50 tests: 49 tests pass and 1 fails locally.
INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
```

with `short` and a test failure:

```
$ bazel test //... --test_summary=short
INFO: Analyzed 50 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 50 test targets...
FAIL: //:test2 (see /home/ahumesky/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ahumesky/d7e5f46ce97861928779430e418f94f3/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/testlogs/test2/test.log)
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.164s, Critical Path: 0.06s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
//:test1                                                        (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test10                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test11                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test12                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.0s
//:test13                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test14                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test15                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test16                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test17                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test18                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test19                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test20                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.0s
//:test21                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test22                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test23                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test24                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test25                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test26                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test27                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test28                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test29                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test3                                                        (cached) PASSED in 0.0s
//:test30                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test31                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test32                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test33                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test34                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test35                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test36                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.2s
//:test37                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.0s
//:test38                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test39                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test4                                                        (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test40                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.0s
//:test41                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test42                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test43                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test44                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.0s
//:test45                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test46                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test47                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.0s
//:test48                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test49                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test5                                                        (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test50                                                       (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test6                                                        (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test7                                                        (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test8                                                        (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test9                                                        (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
//:test2                                                                 FAILED in 0.0s
  /home/ahumesky/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ahumesky/d7e5f46ce97861928779430e418f94f3/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/testlogs/test2/test.log

Executed 1 out of 50 tests: 49 tests pass and 1 fails locally.
INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that `short` might provide more information than `detailed`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [build event protocol](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/build-event-protocol.html) provides all the data you need.

A tool such as [BuildBuddy](https://www.buildbuddy.io/) can visualize the Build Event Protocol for you.

Screenshot from BuildBuddy:

[image]

BuildBuddy shows for example all tests with the corresponding test results. You can click on each individual test and have look on the corresponding logs:

[image]

The Build Event Protocol provides live streaming. This way who can provide your developers with live build/test information.

There is also an commercial-only solution from EngFlow called [Build
Dashboard](https://www.engflow.com/product/buildDashboard?r=menu).

Comment: This looks really cool! We're pretty tied to a different technology for CI at the moment but I'll definitely keep this in mind if we ever get to a mostly-Bazel build setup.